# Using iloc keeps picking the last row of multiple data files

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have a list of 50 .csv files named data1.csv, data2.csv etc, I would like plot the first row, third column of each of these files. But first I would like to check the 50 values to ensure I'm plotting the correct thing, I have:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('data*.csv')

for f in sorted(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print(df.iloc[0,2])
```

The problem here is in the last line, `df.iloc[0,2]` prints the 3rd column of the LAST row when I want it to print the 3rd column of the FIRST row.

Essentially `print(df.iloc[0,2])` prints the same values as `print(df.iloc[-1,2])` and I have no idea why.

How can I check what values the first row, third column are in all of my files?

Comment: What does `print(len(df))` return?

Comment: I get 1, 50 times as I have 50 files

Comment: Have you tried `df.iat[0,2]`?

Comment: Just tried this, gives me the same values as df.iat[-1,2], so incredibly strange

Comment: It sounds like your dataframes are one row long. Because you are creating `df` in a for loop you can call it after the loop is done. Try just `print(df)` _after_ the loop so you can inspect what the dataframe actually looks like

Comment: Printing df in the loop shows me all of the values for all rows that are in the dataframes, printing df after the loop shows me all the rows in the last dataframe of the loop. It's outputting values correctly, but for some reason I just can't pick the first row to observe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, pd.read.csv considers headers, but my .csv files have no headers, so we need:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,headers=None)
```